# Angularjs: dicrective compile and isolated scope this is bad combination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, scope, directive

I trying make a simple directive for internationalization tasks. The directive looks like this

```
angular.module('i18n.test', [])
  .service('i18n', function() {
    this.current = 'ru';
  })
  .directive('test', function(i18n) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        code: '@test'
      },
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
        tElement.text('{{ tostr(text) }}');
        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs){
          scope.text = texts[attrs.test];
          scope.tostr = function(text){
            return text[i18n.current];
          };
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

I discovered that if remove isolated scope then directive works properly, else `{{ tostr(text) }}` calc as empty string. See example on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hV9wOd5oftJZshPLQN4y?p=preview

This is a bug, or I don't understand something?